# How do I get the multiplication symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

How do I use the recurrent multiplication symbol that gives a1*a2*a3*a4*a5*a6......?
I looked it over online and couldn't find it because I don't know the actual name for it.

Comment: Is `\cdot` what you are looking for? [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Do you mean `\prod`, eg `$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}ai$`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Either `\cdot` or `\times`?

Comment: BTW, for symbols this is the relevant reference: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/

Comment: Related: [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Comment: Oh, it was \prod. Thank you for \cdot also, I didn't know this one too.

Comment: @IvanLerner If you already have a `TeX` distribution installed like `TeXLive` or `MikTeX`, you can open your terminal and type `texdoc symbols-a4`. There are a lot of symbols there. Just search for the keyword using your reader's search engine.

Comment: I was editing on Wikipedia, I still don't have any TeX distribution installed. But thank you for the information, it will be usefull.